# difference in output while using return and print keyword

Tags: printing, return, keyword

def func1(*args):
for i in args:
print(i)

func1(10,20,34)

---

### ****in the above code i get the output in the way shown below:****

### 10
20
30

****Now when i code this way i dont get the output as the way i got in the above coding****

def func1(*args):
for i in args:
return(i)

print(func1(10,20,30))

**---------Output-------
10**

**?? Why is only 10 printing here and not all the values passed in the argument**

Answer (score 0):

> **?? Why is only 10 printing here and not all the values passed in the argument**

The loop `for i in args: …` would run through the `…` body three times, once for each of the arguments `10`, `20` and `30`, but only if not exited prematurely, and just that happens in the very first loop run for argument `10` when you use `return(i)`, since `return` immediately leaves the function and there's no coming back.

An alternative is

```
def func1(*args):
    for i in args: yield i
```

therewith you can `print(*func1(10, 20, 30))`.